# How to fix a corrupt server (after upgrade) with chroot in rescue-mode over ssh

Tags: ssh, debian, chroot, troubleshooting

First, I'm NOT trying to create a ssh-jail.

#### Here's the situation

I decided to upgrade my server from Debian 9 to 12. But now I'm locked out.

I went step by step : from 9 to 10, 10 to 11 and 11 to 12, following each time the same process :

- change the repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- `apt update`
- `apt upgrade`
- `apt full-upgrade`
- reboot

It went smoothly, except after the last reboot (in Debian 12), when I tried to ssh on the server, I got a "Connection refused". I checked with `nmap`, the port 22 was no longer open...

I don't have physical access to the server, only via ssh.

#### What I've tried so far

I was able to reboot in rescue mode, and to login via ssh in the rescue OS (Debian 10).

I was able to mount the root filesystem of my corrupt system. And I started looking around in the configuration files, but I couldn't find anything that would indicate that `sshd` was disabled.

My next idea was to chroot in the corrupt filesystem and try to fix my problem : enable sshd or check if some iptables rules (installed with Debian 12 ?) have closed port 22.

The thing is, I've never used chroot and I'm not really comfortable with iptables.

I found inspiration in https://wiki.debian.org/chroot :

```
mount /dev/md3 /mnt/server            # that's obviously the root filesystem of my server
mount --bind /sys /mnt/server/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/server/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/server/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/server/proc
mount --bind /run /mnt/server/run     # maybe this was not a good idea
chroot /mnt/server
```

I noticed a change in my prompt, so I suppose my user's `.bashrc` file was sourced, and I tried enabling `sshd` with `systemctl` but I got an error message :
`Failed to enable unit, refusing to operate on linked unit file sshd.service.`

Then I spent some time reading (RTFM, they said...) and my ssh connection timed out.

When I log back in, I'm in the rescue OS (`/` is the rescue OS root, and my server root filesystem is still mounted in `/mnt/server`). So I assume the chroot died with the ssh session (is this correct ?) However, I'm not able to `umount` :

```
umount /mnt/server/sys                    # ok
umount /mnt/server/dev                    # ok
umount /mnt/server/dev/pts                # ok
umount /mnt/server/proc                   # ok
umount /mnt/server/run                    # not ok
umount: /mnt/server/run: target is busy.
umount /mnt/server                        # not ok
umount: /mnt/server: target is busy.
```

I tried to `umount -f`, same response. It seems I'm stuck half-way in and out of chroot...

`lsof /mnt/server/run` shows quite a list of processes that seem very much system-related, so I'm not sure it's safe to kill them all...

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd       1 root   66u  FIFO   0,21      0t0   72 /run/initctl
systemd       1 root   70u  FIFO   0,21      0t0   47 /run/dmeventd-server
systemd       1 root   71u  FIFO   0,21      0t0   48 /run/dmeventd-client
systemd-j   333 root  mem    REG   0,21  1310720 1988 /run/log/journal/27246933cf104042b7aae4c021b5e14e/system.journal
systemd-j   333 root  mem    REG   0,21  1310720 1987 /run/log/journal/27246933cf104042b7aae4c021b5e14e/system@8b38c633380f402087964636cbfb1666-000000000000a96c-00060ac0e0953243.journal
systemd-j   333 root  mem    REG   0,21        8   78 /run/systemd/journal/kernel-seqnum
systemd-j   333 root   15u   REG   0,21  1310720 1987 /run/log/journal/27246933cf104042b7aae4c021b5e14e/system@8b38c633380f402087964636cbfb1666-000000000000a96c-00060ac0e0953243.journal
systemd-j   333 root   21u   REG   0,21  1310720 1988 /run/log/journal/27246933cf104042b7aae4c021b5e14e/system.journal
systemd-l   557 root   10r  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1609 /run/systemd/sessions/c1.ref
systemd-l   557 root   16r  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1900 /run/systemd/sessions/c6.ref
systemd-l   557 root   17r  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1911 /run/systemd/sessions/c7.ref
systemd-l   557 root   18r  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1993 /run/systemd/sessions/c10.ref
systemd-l   557 root   19r  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1969 /run/systemd/sessions/c9.ref
cron        558 root    3uW  REG   0,21        4 1571 /run/crond.pid
su          714 root    6w  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1609 /run/systemd/sessions/c1.ref
sshd       6314 root    8w  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1993 /run/systemd/sessions/c10.ref
sshd      17335 root    8w  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1900 /run/systemd/sessions/c6.ref
sshd      21595 root    8w  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1969 /run/systemd/sessions/c9.ref
sshd      29605 root    8w  FIFO   0,21      0t0 1911 /run/systemd/sessions/c7.ref
```

So here are my questions (so far) :

- is it correct to assume the chroot died with the ssh session ?
- if not, where in the matrix am I ?
- is it necessary/safe to `mount bind` `/sys`, `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc`, and `/run` in the chrooted environment ?
- if I were to use `screen`, could I run chroot in a window and keep the rescue OS root in another ?
- I suppose neither the chroot nor the mount would persist after a reboot, would they ? (I'm gonna find out any moment, cuz that's my next step...)

(I'll edit the question along the way to indicate my progress and actually get to the main question)

Comment: normally, a fresh installation and copy over the configuration is faster as a upgrade from a stale release

Comment: by the way, the Debian recommended way of upgrading bullseye to bookworm (and perhaps earlier upgrades too), the `apt upgrade` step is suggested as `apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs`

Comment: sorry guys, but I'm not asking what I should have done, but what I can do now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would boot using a live cd and then mount the root partition of your broken system. For example `mount /dev/sdXY /mnt` then `chroot /mnt`
Then flush all iptables rules `iptables -F`. Then exit the chroot and umount the root partition.

For ssh,the ssh service in Debian is not called sshd but ssh.

1. Mount the root partition again and mount some extra essential
   directories.
   `mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

   `mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`

   `mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
2. Enter the chroot again `chroot /mnt` And check the status of the ssh
   service `systemctl status ssh`. Also make sure openssh-server is installed and if
   it's not installed run apt-get install openssh-server. You can also try to enable it using `systemctl enable ssh`
3. If your ssh configuration is broken you might need to reset it using
   `mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`
4. Once your done exit chroot, and unmount everything.

   `umount /mnt/dev`

   `umount /mnt/proc`

   `umount /mnt/sys`

   `umount /mnt`
5. And then reboot

Comment: iptables had no rules in the chroot, but enabling the ssh service did the job, thanks (a lot !)

Comment: strange thing : I upgraded the kernel and the ssh service was disabled after reboot. I had to go through the mount / chroot / systemctl enable ssh / umount process again to re-enable it. It's working fine now, but that ssh gets disabled on upgrades seems weird...